# converting xml to soap request in camel

Tags: xml, apache-camel

trying to read xml file from source system and mapping to target system attribute and then creating SOAP request out of it to call target system SOAP call.

1) convert input xml to output xml using xslt.
2) create SOAP xml using xslt
3) pass the SOAP xml as payload to target system SOAP call.

I want to try to achieve this without using xslt transformations.

Please provide input on the same.

Comment: If you don't want to use xslt component, you can use the camel bean component for your transformations.
Look for examples with bean as endpoint. See [camel bean component](http://camel.apache.org/bean.html)

Comment: If you would like to avoid using xslt why not unmarshal your XML using Jaxb, then use a typeconverter to convert that object representation to your desired object representation, then use Jaxb to marshal the object?